# Matter.js set limits (edges) of the World

Tags: javascript, matter.js

Is there a way to give limits to my World in Matter.js. By this, I mean like any bodies from any masks, groups or category can cross these limits. I know there are World.bounds that define collision detections of the world.

Comment: What is wrong with World.bounds ?

Comment: @NikolaLukic World.bounds won't stop velocity from bodies and etc. It will only stop to get events from collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not relevant anymore.
But try to change **thickness** of the bounds. Change them to 1024 as example. It should help in your case.